# Select Picture Inside a Textbox Shape

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with Picture inside a textbox. I just want to select that picure inside textbox and get its picture properties using VBA in word

I have tried to select all contents of the textbox but that results in error in getting picture properties.

Any suggestions how it can be done?

Comment: By "textbox" are you referring to the VBA `TextBox` control or to a Word "text box" shape?

Comment: word text box shape

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question

Comment: `ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Fill.UserPicture(Filename)` - This looks like it will set the image for the first shape in the document. (They all have names too) Hopefully that's enough to get you started, because this is not exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is text inside the textbox as well as the picture it will be an InlineShape. In this case you can get to the properties like so:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.InlineShapes(1)
```

You do not need to select the picture to get its properties.